# Trigger and Signal Logic

Tags: mysql

I am building a prison management database for a DB course and I am working on a trigger to reject an insert if the start date and end date of a prisoners sentence are incorrect.

I am aware that there are better ways to do this, but I am required to use a trigger.

Here's what I've come up with, I don't know if I am correctly using the SIGNAL feature:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Prisoner_Date_Check` BEFORE INSERT ON `Prisoner`
    FOR EACH ROW begin
    if (new.sentence_end-new.sentence_start) < 0 then
        SIGNAL sqlstate '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect Prisoner.start_date or Prisoner.end_date';
    END IF;
    if new.sentence_end < current_date then
        SIGNAL sqlstate '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect Prisoner.end_date, less than current_date';
    END IF;
    if new.sentence_start > current_date then
        SIGNAL sqlstate '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Incorrect Prisoner.start_date, greater than current_date';
    end if;
END$$
```

And when I run the script, I get this error.

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

Answer (score 0):

This usage of `SIGNAL` is fine.

What is failing here is the `CREATE TRIGGER`, because another trigger was already defined for the same table for the same event.

Use `DROP TRIGGER` first.